# jackson ignore field during object creation

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have one problem.

let's say i have a model

```
public class Student{
     private int id;
     private String name;

   //getters and setters
}
```

Then i need to create 2 objects in different classes using Student model. In first class i need to create object with 2 fields, in second class with just one field.

```
public class ClassA{
     Student student = new Student();
     student.setId(id);
     student.setName(name);
}
```

and

```
public class ClassB{
     Student student = new Student();
     student.setId(id);
}
```

Then in second class even though i do not use second field, it is still being added as null.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Is this for serialization or deserialization? What do you expect the value of 2nd field (name) in `ClassB`?

Comment: This is for serialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jackson annotation to ignore null values in result JSON.

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class ClassB{...}
```

Read more here:
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the ObjectMapper to read the data you can ignore the unknown values as shown below.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```